# Django update method updates already loaded objects?

Tags: django

Ok so I ran into something that I find really weird but seems pretty basic. Consider the following:

```
>>> users = Usr.objects.filter(refresh=True)
>>> users
[<Usr: Usr object>, <Usr: Usr object>, <Usr: Usr object>, <Usr: Usr object>]
>>> Usr.objects.filter(refresh=True).update(refresh=False)
>>> users
[]
```

So when calling `update()` Django update rows in the DB AND the objects previously loaded??

Django docs on `update()` don't talk about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update()` does not affect already fetched objects.

Reason you get empty list: Accessing `users` after the delete cause another query execution. (`users` is QuerySet object; [`Querysets are lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)); you see the state after the delete.

If you retrieve the filter value and save it as sequence object, you will get different result.

For example, try following:

```
users = list(Usr.objects.filter(refresh=True))
print(users)
Usr.objects.filter(refresh=True).update(refresh=False)
print(users)
```